# How to create sequential numbering against two select statements that are unioned?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, salesforce

I have a SQL query that is just a union between two `SELECT` statements.  Say the result of the overall query produces 10 records.  I want as part of that result set a column that is a numeric and sequential (like a primary key - 0,1,2,3, and so on).  My problem is the way I have this coded, as you can see below, doesn't produce unique values (the 0 value is repeated twice, the 1 value is repeated twice, as expected, because of the union statement).  How can I get the below "Transaction Sequence Number" to display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10?  Instead of 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5?

Here's my code (below).  I will be posting a screenshot of my result set shortly - SQL Server is being incredibly slow for me right now - I hope this makes sense without a screenshot of the result set:

```
select top 5
    'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
    row_number() over (order by s.HL_ACCT_ID) as 'Transaction Sequence Number',
    s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
    null as [AcctNumber],
    null as [AcctType],
    null as [AcctSource],
    null as [DUNS_NBR],
    null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
    s.CAMPAIGNCODE as [CellCode],
    '-1' as [OfferCode],
    case
        when c.EventDate is not null then 'Click'
        when c.EventDate is null then
        case 
            when sub.status = 'unsubscribed' then 'Unsubscribe'
            when sub.status = 'bounced' then 'Bounce'
            when sub.status = 'held' then 'Bounce'
        end
    end as [ResponseType],
    convert(varchar, c.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
    null as [ResponseQuantity],
    null as [ResponseValue],
    'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
    null as [Cookie ID],
    null as [IP address],
    null as [Device ID],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
from cXXXXXXX.sendlog s with (nolock)
inner join cXXXXXXX._subscribers sub with (nolock) on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
left join cXXXXXXX._click c with (nolock) on c.JobID = s.JobID and c.SubscriberKey = s.Email
where c.EventDate is not null or (c.EventDate is null and (sub.status = 'unsubscribed' or sub.status = 'bounced' or sub.status = 'held')) and c.isunique = 1

union all

select top 5
    'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
    (row_number() over (order by s.HL_ACCT_ID)) + 1 as 'Transaction Sequence Number',
    s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
    null as [AcctNumber],
    null as [AcctType],
    null as [AcctSource],
    null as [DUNS_NBR],
    null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
    s.CAMPAIGNCODE as [CellCode],
    '-1' as [OfferCode],
    case
        when o.EventDate is not null then 'Message Open'
        when o.EventDate is null then
        case 
            when sub.status = 'unsubscribed' then 'Unsubscribe'
            when sub.status = 'bounced' then 'Bounce'
            when sub.status = 'held' then 'Bounce'
        end
    end as [ResponseType],
    convert(varchar, o.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
    null as [ResponseQuantity],
    null as [ResponseValue],
    'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
    null as [Cookie ID],
    null as [IP address],
    null as [Device ID],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
    null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
from cXXXXXXX.sendlog s with (nolock)
inner join cXXXXXXX._subscribers sub with (nolock) on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
left join cXXXXXXX._open o with (nolock) on o.JobID = s.JobID and o.SubscriberKey = s.Email
where o.EventDate is not null or (o.EventDate is null and (sub.status = 'unsubscribed' or sub.status = 'bounced' or sub.status = 'held'))  and o.isunique = 1
```

Comment: You could try joining the whole query (both unions) against another table, and do the row_number in the outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose your sql in a common table expression and then number them:

```
;WITH CTE AS(your sql...)
SELECT *,
 (row_number() over (order by HL_ACCT_ID)) + 1 as 'Transaction Sequence Number'
FROM CTE
```

You have to make sure you have unique column names in the cte. Also, if you are using this sql statement with other statements, make sure you add a ';' before it or end the previous statement with a ';'.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA.HL_ACCT_ID),DATA.* FROM 
(your query here...)DATA
```